# Filtering data by posted arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, arrays

I have a table with data like this:

```
articles. id   | author                | title     | content  | type
             1 | author1, author2      | thetitle1 | text1    | typeA
             2 | author1               | thetitle2 | text2    | typeB
             3 | author2               | thetitle3 | text3    | typeA
```

Posted array is a filters for this:

```
$conditions = array();
$where = '';

if(isset($_POST['authors'])){ //empty, is_array and etc.
  $authors = $_POST['authors']; // [ author1, author2 ]
  $conditions[] = "author IN ('".implode("','",$authors)."')";
}
if(isset($_POST['types'])){
  $types = $_POST['types']; // [ typeA, typeB ]
  $conditions[] = "type IN ('".implode("','",$types)."')";
}

if(!empty($conditions)){
  $where = ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles".$where;
```

Seems all is okey, but the field `author` can contain a few authors, separated by comma, so the filter `author IN ('author1')` will not work. How to select all the articles where `author1` is involved (in this case it's first & second records)?

Comment: Either NORMALIZE your database so article_authors is a separate table, or use MySQL's [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.... then read about SQL injection and escaping... even better, switch to prepared statements using MySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change the database structure. Searching via string is slow(ish), this might work now, but when the dataset increases, this will become a drag.

I think something like this would be better:

```
author
--------
id  name  
1   author1
2   author2

books:
--------
id  title  
1   Some Book  
2   Some Other Book  

author_book:
--------
id  author_id  book_id
1     1         1
2     1         2
3     2         2
```

In my example author1 has written book 1&2, and author2 has written book 2
The other was arround: Book 1 has been writter by author 1, book2 by author1&2

It's way more flexible in the long run. Proper database structure is very important to start with

Comment: I can't edit so much the database, after that I'll have to edit a lot of things.

Comment: @AviAtion your schema design is bad and you'll regret not normalizing it at the beginning of your work. This project will drag and possibly fail later on.

Comment: This is not my guilt, I have what I have.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Martijn, but if You cant change DB You can try something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['authors'])){ //empty, is_array and etc.
  $authors = $_POST['authors']; // [ author1, author2 ]
  $subC = array();
  $subC [] = " ( author IN ('".implode("','",$authors)."') ) ";
  foreach ($authors as $a){
      $subC [] = " ( author LIKE %$a% ) " ;
  }

  $subC = ' ( ' . implode (' OR ' , $subC) . ' ) ';

  $conditions[] = $subC;
}
```

It's far from perfect, but should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (http://codepad.org/wjISZj54)

```
   <?php
 $authors = array('abc','def','asd'); 

$types=array('type1','type2');

$authorarr=array();
foreach($authors as $author)
{
 $authorarr[]="'".$author."'";
}

$authorstr=implode(',',$authorarr);

   $conditions[] = "author IN ($authorstr)";


$typearr=array();
foreach($types as $type)
{
 $typearr[]="'".$type."'";
}

$typestr=implode(',',$typearr);

   $conditions[] = "type IN ($typestr)";



if(!empty($conditions)){
  $where = ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles".$where;



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your structure saving comma separated values  is not a good practice for your problem you can use the `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE type IN (...) OR FIND_IN_SET("author1", author)
```

other you can also use the LIKE to match the desired result but it is not a good idea

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE type IN (...) OR  author LIKE '%author1%';
```

Here is the reference [**Find in set**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)